# How to play code if element found on page

Tags: imacros

If an element in a variable "group" is found on a webpage, the play code should execute. If not then it should have the browser go back to the previous page. How should this if statement be properly implemented?

```
var group = 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:"post_field"';

if(opengroup) {
        iimPlayCode('SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST\nADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=url.txt ')
    } else {
        iimPlayCode('URL GOTO=javascript:window.content.history.back()');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
var opengroup = iimPlayCode("SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n" + 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:"post_field"');
if (opengroup == 1)
    iimPlayCode('SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST\nADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=url.txt ')
else
    iimPlayCode('URL GOTO=javascript:window.content.history.back()');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to create an if statement. This can be achieved by either converting the java to iMacros using EVAL, here's an example of one i used once:

```
URL GOTO=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
WAIT SECONDS=1

'Set the VAR1 to the current url= https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
SET !VAR1 {{!URLCURRENT}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Featured_content
WAIT SECONDS=1

'Set the VAR2 to the current url= https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Featured_content
SET !VAR2 {{!URLCURRENT}}

'   1.Now !VAR3 is our answer from the if statement
'   2.We need to assign the text from {{!VAR1}} to a var x,y,z,...
'     In this case, we use the letter d and s, and assign text with \"....\" to the var
'   3.We check if d and s are equal by if (d==s), there is also not equal (d!=s)
'     Or bigger(but only for numbers) (d>s) or smaller (d<s)
'   4.After the if we say what !VAR3 should become if the if statement is right
'     This is done by creating a new var (in this case the x)
'     However the output shall be again a text, so we assign x to https://www.google.de
'     And do this by assigning text to a var with  \"....\"        so in this case {var x = \"https://www.google.de\";}
'   5.After that we add the else, if the statement was false, and assign x to the text, which should
'         !Be VAR3  when the statement was wrong, and we do this again the same way        so in this case {var x=\"https://www.youtube.com\";}
'       6. At the end we "call" x and tell that whatever x has become, it is now !VAR3

SET !VAR3 EVAL("var d=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; var s=\"{{!VAR2}}\" ; if (d==s){var x = \"https://www.google.de\";} else {var x=\"https://www.youtube.com\";} x;")

'checking if code worked (and it did)
URL GOTO={{!VAR3}}

'you can of course change the SET !VAR1 or !VAR2 to some text inside a page, or whatever you like
```